# how to make transmitter and receiver for quad copter?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I want to make a transmitter and receiver for quad copter for that I am using two arduinos(UNO and nano).I am using 4 pots for controlling the brushless motors.For that I am sending 4 integer values of the pots and with that integer value PWM signals are generated at receiver by the arduino.Now I want to know how to send that 4 integer values of the pots serially using arduino.

Answer (score 1):

The APC220 radio module provides a simple and economic solution to wireless data communications. Integrates an embedded high speed microprocessor and high performance IC that creates a transparent UART/TTL interface, and elminates any need for packetizing and data encoding. Use this module as this works as a pair and more intriguing part is that "it" can transmit over a km away.

link ~http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&filter_name=apc&product_id=57#.VWeKIVWqqko

Comment: Thanks,that's fine,but I want to know how to convert parallel data to serial data of the integer values using arduino.

Comment: Just elaborate on the data type you are talking about, then may be you can be directed properly